# How to persist JSR-310 types with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: jpa, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, java-time

I am trying to use Spring Data JPA 1.8 with the Java 8 Date/Time API JSR-310.

Everything seems to work, until I try to get all Vehicles between two LocalDateTimes.
The number of Entities returned seems to only have a loose correlation with the number it should.

### Entity

```java
@Repository
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long> {

    List<Vehicle> findByDateTimeBetween(LocalDateTime begin, LocalDateTime end);

}
```

### Repository

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "IDX", nullable = false, unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long vehicleId;

  @Column(name = "DATE_TIME", nullable = false)
  private LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

  // Getters and Setters

}
```

### Relevant Dependencies

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.186</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Failing Test Example

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:applicationContextTesting.xml"})
@Transactional
public class VehicleRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;

    @Test
    public void testVehicleBetween() {
        // Given
        Vehicle vehicleMarch1Twelve = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle vehicleMarch1Eighteen = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle vehicleMarch2Five = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle vehicleMarch2Six = new Vehicle();
        LocalDateTime march1Twelve = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.MARCH, 1, 12, 0);
        LocalDateTime march1Eighteen = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.MARCH, 1, 18, 0);
        LocalDateTime march2Five = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.MARCH, 2, 5, 0);
        LocalDateTime march2Six = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.MARCH, 2, 6, 0);
        vehicleMarch1Twelve.setDateTime(march1Twelve);
        vehicleMarch1Eighteen.setDateTime(march1Eighteen);
        vehicleMarch2Five.setDateTime(march2Five);
        vehicleMarch2Six.setDateTime(march2Six);

        vehicleRepository.save(vehicleMarch1Twelve);
        vehicleRepository.save(vehicleMarch1Eighteen);
        vehicleRepository.save(vehicleMarch2Five);
        vehicleRepository.save(vehicleMarch2Six);
        vehicleRepository.flush();

        // when
        List<Vehicle> allVehicles = vehicleRepository.findByDateTimeBetween(
            march1Twelve,
            march2Six);
        List<Vehicle> allVehicles2 = vehicleRepository.findByDateTimeBetween(
            march1Twelve.minusMinutes(2),
            march2Six.plusMinutes(2));
        List<Vehicle> threeVehicles = vehicleRepository.findByDateTimeBetween(
            march1Twelve.plusMinutes(2),
            march2Six);
        List<Vehicle> twoVehicles = vehicleRepository.findByDateTimeBetween(
            march1Twelve.plusMinutes(2),
            march2Six.minusMinutes(2));
        List<Vehicle> oneVehicles = vehicleRepository.findByDateTimeBetween(
            march1Twelve.plusMinutes(2),
            march2Six.minusHours(3));

        // then
        Assert.assertTrue("size was " + allVehicles.size(), allVehicles.size() == 4);
        Assert.assertTrue("size was " + allVehicles2.size(), allVehicles2.size() == 4);
        Assert.assertTrue("size was " + threeVehicles.size(), threeVehicles.size() == 3);
        Assert.assertTrue("size was " + twoVehicles.size(), twoVehicles.size() == 2);
        Assert.assertTrue("size was " + oneVehicles.size(), oneVehicles.size() == 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(oneVehicles.get(0).getDateTime().equals(march1Eighteen));
    }

}
```

The first List contains 2 elements (should be 4). All other List contain **0** elements!
Given the second request is for a greater timespan than the first.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

### Edit

Thank you [@Oliver Gierke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-gierke) for the quick answer.
I was able to fix the issue by adding "org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten" to the packagesToScan property. Now it seems to work properly.

As reference here is my working Database related (testing) configuration.

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:testing"/>
    <property name="username" value="interface"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="hikariConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.project.domain,org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.company.project.dao" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

UPDATE: The answer below is valid if you need to stay on a Hibernate version < 5.0. Hibernate 5.0 supports persisting JSR-310 date/time types out of the box. I.e. if you are on Hibernate 5.0 or newer, [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997296/18122) is the way to go. Everyone else, read on.

The root cause for this at none of the widely used JPA providers actually support JSR-310 types out of the box yet. However, as of Spring Data JPA 1.8.0 we ship JPA 2.0 converters that will translate non-time-zoned JSR-310 types into a legacy `Date` so that they can be persisted as is.

To get this working, simply register `org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters` as one of the managed JPA classes with your provider. There's a couple of way to do that: in a very standard JPA setup you list it in your `persistence.xml`. In a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` based setup you can just add the package of the class to the `packagesToScan` property. If you're using Spring Boot adding the class to the `@EntityScan` annotation does the trick.

The latter is described in a bit more detail in the [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler#jsr-310-and-threeten-backport-support) covering the new features the Spring Data release train named Fowler ships

Comment: Correction: DataNucleus JPA supports java.time types out of the box and has since a year ago (when Java8 came out), and I've been using that support.

Comment: With  JPA 2.2  this bug will be fix, will have any problem with this class of spring data?

Comment: That's not a bug, it's just how things work. Unfortunately I am not able to predict 2018 ;).

Comment: Just a hint for spring-boot users. I'm using `springBootVersion = '1.2.7.RELEASE'` which is currently the latest and it comes with `spring-data-jpa:1.7.4.RELEASE` - so due to the answer you need to update the data-jpa dependency if you are going with spring boot

Comment: thank you for the answer, adding `Jsr310JpaConverters` to `@EntityScan` in a Spring Boot app made the trick for me. However, when I added hibernate envers for auditing and marked an entity with JSR310 type to be audited, it throws `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: BasicType adapter for AttributeConverter<Instant,Date>, at table:`, I guess envers is not aware of these converters, is there an elegant way to fix this? I am using spring boot `1.3.3.RELEASE` and cloud `Brixton.M4`. thank you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, adding Jsr310JpaConverters,it throw `classnotfoundexception: org.threeten.bp.localdatetime`.Need I add `org.threeten` dependency?

Answer (score 34):

When using Hibernate >=5.0, <5.2, you can drop in

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

on your classpath which will automatically register `Type`s corresponding to the JSR310 classes.

(Thanks @AbhijitSarkar) Since 5.2, "the hibernate-java8 module has been merged into hibernate-core and the Java 8 date/time types are now natively supported." ([Migration Guide 5.2](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2))

Answer (score 21):

It took me quite a while to figure out how to use `LocalDateTime` in my JPA Entity. I was on the latest Spring boot version. And debugged a lot into the ConversionServices.

Oliver Gierkes answer helped me a lot in getting to the final working setup:

**Add Spring-data-jpa 1.8.0 or higher to your dependency management**

```
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.8.2.RELEASE")
```

**Enable @EntityScan for the Jsr310JpaConverters + (at least) your Application.class**

```
@EntityScan(
  basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class }
)
@SpringBootApplication
class Application { … }
```

Comment: works for me. there is a sample project on java8 features on github too. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/java8

Comment: I could not get this to work with curated dependencies of Spring-boot 1.5.8. (it comes with hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar). I had to add org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.1.0.Final to get it to work.

Comment: Can I use it if mysql datatype is `TIMESTAMP`?