# Spring Data (Rest): Date serialization mapping returns a wrong value

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Boot and Data Rest to create a simple microservice in Java8 and get a wrong serialized value in a Date attribute in my JSON response.

My entity:

```
@Entity
public class ArchivedInvoice implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Column
    private java.util.Date invoiceDate;
    ...
}
```

My repository interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "archivedinvoices", path = "archivedinvoices")
public interface ArchivedInvoiceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository < ArchivedInvoice, Long > {
    ...
        @RestResource(rel = "findByDate", path = "findByDate")
        public Page< ArchivedInvoice > findByInvoiceDate(@Param("invoiceDate") @Nullable @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) Date invoiceDate, Pageable pageable);
    ...
}
```

Postgres saves the attribute in a simple date (invoice_date date NOT NULL - '2016-02-22') but the JSON response returns:

```
  "invoiceDate" : "2016-02-21T23:00:00.000+0000"
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You just need a [`@Temporal(DATE)` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html) on the field. Without it JPA will treat that field as a `timestamp` (apparently with time zone).

Comment: This works also fine, when I remove the @DateTimeFormat annotation! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is actually a timestamp:

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond
>   precision.

Use `java.sql.Date` instead if the SQL type is date.
Or if you use java 8, you can try using `java.time.LocalDate`. For that to work you will need to [register Springs JSR310 JPA converters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29542062/4248317).

Comment: Well, `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`, so (in theory) it also can represent a specific instant in time. The only difference is in their default bindings.

Comment: Sure, but why would you use `java.util.Date` if `java.sql.Date` is designed to represent the SQL type date?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I get now this exception:
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Date] to type [@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date]

Comment: The query parameter in your repository should also be java.sql.Date and you don't need the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation.

Comment: sorry, actually not sure about the annotation.

Comment: It works, when I remove the annotation and use java.sql.Date. Thanks!