# Why Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE doesn't support LocalDateTime of Java 8 automatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have a Spring Boot application and I use LocalDateTime but I need to explicit configure the converter of Jsr310 for my LocalDateTime property:

---

Application.class (the main class)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

Entity example:

```
@Entity
public class News {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime datetime;

    ...
```

---

Repository:

```
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("DELETE FROM News n WHERE n.datetime  < :datetime")
    void deleteByDatetimeBefore(@Param("datetime") LocalDateTime datetime);

}
```

---

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>Test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Not should be automatic? Why I need configure this?

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
```

And why I need to write the delete Query:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM News n WHERE n.datetime  < :datetime")
        void deleteByDatetimeBefore(@Param("datetime") LocalDateTime datetime);
```

This should not be automatic like:

```
@Transactional
Long deleteByDatetimeBefore(LocalDateTime datetime);
```

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517508/how-to-persist-jsr-310-types-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: I knew this information... but wanted to know why this config is not automatic.

Comment: I thought it did provide some explanation, perhaps you were hoping for something more.. "The root cause for this at none of the widely used JPA providers actually support JSR-310 types out of the box yet."

Comment: Thanks Alex! This was my doubt.