# LocalTime with spring-data-jpa and mssql

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have issue with query which is working with LocalTime on MSSQL DB

Our entity has field

```
@Column(name = "receipt_time", nullable = false)
private LocalTime receiptTime;
```

Everything works fine except when querying i.e. using spring-data-jpa query

```
boolean existsByReceiptTime(LocalTime time);
```

Returns `The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

I tried to resolve with sendTimeAsDateTime, but it didn't work. The url string was not accepted. Then I tried with some AttributeConverters to no avail. Any other possible advices? NOTE: I really like to stay with LocalTime type.

UPDATE:
query generated is

```
Hibernate: select TOP(?) receipt0_.id as col_0_0_ from receipt receipt0_ where receipt0_.receipt_time=?' is the query.
```

Comment: We are using correct dialect also SQLServer2012Dialect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517508/how-to-persist-jsr-310-types-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: I actually wrote my own converter, it didn't help. Will try with the one mentioned in link above

Comment: define what "existsByReceiptTime" is generating in terms of JPQL. Also it is your JPA provider handling the query not Spring, so the stack trace from whichever JPA provider is used

Comment: Here we are over 4 years later and I still have the same problem with spring boot 2.6.3, LocalTime columns cause errors in queries.  Any new solution to this aside from writing a converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to write custom attribute converter. It is probably Microsoft SQL server specific solution.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalTime, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime time) {
       return time.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(String time) {
       return LocalTime.parse(time);
    }
}
```