# Instant type and Date type

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink

I had an entity with variable `created` type `Date`

```
public class UserEntity {
...
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date created;
...
}
```

the table created a column with the type `TIMESTAMP` and correctly added the object to the table

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2018-05-02 21:54:25.578--ClientSession(210949780)--Connection(1559972721)--INSERT INTO users (activation_token, avatar_id_in_cloud, avatar_provider, created, email, email_change_token, enabled, entity_version, modified_date, new_email, password, unique_id, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [null, null, null, [here created ==> 2018-05-02 21:54:25.279 <== here created, TkM2Gs9Hrd@gmail.com, null, true, 1, B@6f8060ac, null, $2a$12$/MwdBoXwBgHlxnsicVW.w.UWdYo6ulLH87aZtSxhdbBYA.9QacUXy, 74a45e29-c1f8-40dc-ac25-a7196d7870b4, JonkiPro]
```

however, according to Java 8, I changed the `Date` type to `Instant`.

```
public class UserEntity {
{
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Instant created;
...
}
```

Now it automatically creates a table with a `LONGVARBINARY` created column, the generated command looks like this

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2018-05-02 21:54:25.578--ClientSession(210949780)--Connection(1559972721)--INSERT INTO users (activation_token, avatar_id_in_cloud, avatar_provider, created, email, email_change_token, enabled, entity_version, modified_date, new_email, password, unique_id, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [null, null, null, [here created ==> B@6f8060ac <== here created, TkM2Gs9Hrd@gmail.com, null, true, 1, B@6f8060ac, null, $2a$12$/MwdBoXwBgHlxnsicVW.w.UWdYo6ulLH87aZtSxhdbBYA.9QacUXy, 74a45e29-c1f8-40dc-ac25-a7196d7870b4, JonkiPro]
```

instead of the date there is a string `B@6f8060ac`, and in the database it is already written as `aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870770d02000000005aea177110a133c078`. What is happening with the date? I'm using the H2 base and EclipseLink.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718471/303810.

Comment: Agree @lexicore. Eclipselink 2.7 implements JPA 2.2 officjally (so Java 8 date time). JPA 2.0 (Eclipselink 2.5/2.6) use converter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036493/spring-data-jpa-with-java-8-localdatetime/46036781#46036781

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Instant` type isn't supported by JPA, not even the latest version 2.2 which supports most of the new time types.

`Instant` type is supported by Hibernate and DataNucleus, which map it automatically to a `TIMESTAMP`. But this isn't true for EclipseLink, which treat it as any other object and uses serialization to store it to the database.

The JPA 2.2 spec lists only the following types treated in a special way:

> Java primitive types, java.lang.String, java.math.BigInteger, java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp, byte[], Byte[], char[], Character[], java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalTime, java.time.LocalDateTime, java.time.OffsetTime, java.time.OffsetDateTime

All others, including `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` are supported as any other Serialiazable type, unless the implementation does more than the specification requires (Hibernate and DataNucleus do, EclipseLink doesn't). This will hopefully get fixed in the future in EclipseLink and the next version of the JPA spec.

Comment: I created an issue for EclipseLink about this here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/259