# Spring Data JPA - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot and Spring JPA. I have a repository class with custom `@Query` methods.

```
public interface MarketForceRepository extends CrudRepository<MarketForceComment, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id = ?1 and c.commentDate >= '?1' AND  c.commentDate <= '?2'")
    List<MarketForceComment> getByPropAndDate(Integer propID, LocalDate start, LocalDate end);

    @Query("SELECT c FROM MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id IN ?1 and c.commentDate >= '?2' AND c.commentDate <= '?3'")
    List<MarketForceComment> getByPropsAndDates(List<Integer> propIDs, LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
}
```

The `MarketForceComment` class follows (in part):

```
@Table(name = "MarketForceComment", schema = "dmb")
@Entity
public class MarketForceComment {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PropertyID")
    private Property property;

    @Column(name = "CommentDate")
    private LocalDate commentDate;

    @Column(name = "Level")
    private int level;

    @Column(name = "Subject")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "Details", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String details;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;  

    .... 
}
```

Whenever I attempt to run my query method:

```
@Override
public List<CommentDTO> getCommentsByStore(int storeID, LocalDate date) {
    List<CommentDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    marketRepo.getByPropAndDate(storeID, date.plusMonths(1), date)
            .forEach(c -> dtoList.add(mapper.map(c, CommentDTO.class)));
    guestRepo.getByPropAndDate(storeID, date.plusMonths(1).atStartOfDay(), date.atStartOfDay())
            .forEach(c -> dtoList.add(mapper.map(c, CommentDTO.class)));
    return dtoList;
}
```

I receive the following error: 

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

I am a bit perplexed. It appears to be a format issue (the DBMS wants a 'yyyy-MM-dd' or similar format), yet I thought Java's LocalDate would be expressed/converted into a format that could be parsed by database system.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT:

For reference, the underlying fault was the order of the parameters (?1, ?2, ?3):

```
public interface MarketForceRepository extends CrudRepository<MarketForceComment, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id = ?1 and c.commentDate >= ?2 AND  c.commentDate <= ?3")
    List<MarketForceComment> getByPropAndDate(Integer propID, LocalDate start, LocalDate end);

    @Query("SELECT c FROM MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id IN ?1 and c.commentDate >= ?2 AND c.commentDate <= ?3")
    List<MarketForceComment> getByPropsAndDates(List<Integer> propIDs, LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JPA version lower than 2.2, it doesn't directly support Java8 LocalDate & LocalTime conversion from SqlDate, as it was released before Java8. You will have to write your custom date converter by implementing JPA `AttributeConverter` interface. Then either you can `autoApply` it for all entity classes or you can selectively annotate it to LocalDate entity field.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate date) {        
        return Date.valueOf(date);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date value) {
        return value.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

With `autoApply = true` JPA will automatically associate this converter whereaever Entity fields are LocalDate.

Or if you choose `autoApply = false`, you will have to associate converter class via annotation with the field.

```
@Column(name = "CommentDate")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
private LocalDate commentDate;
```

Refer [JPA 2.2 release spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/63)

Comment: Thanks. However, whenever I add the class, I received the following error on startup: `Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: AttributeConverter domain-model attribute type [java.time.LocalDate] and JDBC type [java.util.Date] did not match query literal type [java.lang.String]`

Comment: `@Query("SELECT c FROM MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id = ?1 and c.commentDate >= '?1' AND  c.commentDate <= '?2'")
    List<MarketForceComment> getByPropAndDate(Integer propID, LocalDate start, LocalDate end);`

shouldn't it be `c.commentDate >= '?2'`, a typo error.

Comment: I updated my answer for conversion directly between LocalDate & SqlDate, that's precise & quicker.

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid I am still getting an error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: AttributeConverter domain-model attribute type [java.time.LocalDate] and JDBC type [java.sql.Date] did not match query literal type [java.lang.String] [SELECT c FROM com.midamcorp.dmb.model.MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id = ?1 and c.commentDate BETWEEN '?1' AND '?2']`.

Comment: I think you have a typo error here, you are not using the correct placeholder#
`[SELECT c FROM com.midamcorp.dmb.model.MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id = ?1 and c.commentDate BETWEEN '?1' AND '?2']`

whereas it should be:

`[SELECT c FROM com.midamcorp.dmb.model.MarketForceComment c WHERE c.property.id = ?1 and c.commentDate BETWEEN '?2' AND '?3']`

Comment: Thanks so much, @Amith Kumar. Part of me hates that it was so simple, but the type/misplaced parameters were the underlying problem. When I placed them correctly, the `@Query` worked correctly; I just had to remove the `'` marks.

Comment: oh! yeah I didn't pay attention too on the quotes you are using. Yeah you didn't need it at first place :). You should update your question block as well, so it doesn't create confusion to anybody refering this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at: [How to persist JSR-310 types with Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517508/how-to-persist-jsr-310-types-with-spring-data-jpa)

Depending on the framework versions you use, you have to add additional configuration to your project to use JSR-310 types like LocalDate in your entities.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the versions. I am using Spring Boot 2 with the corresponding `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either use converter or column definition

for example

```
@Column(name = "local_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
private LocalTime localTime;

@Column(name = "local_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
private LocalDate localDate;

@Column(name = "local_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
```

using converter

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
@Column(name = "createdDate")
private LocalDate createdDate;
```