# jpa query between two dates

Tags: java, spring, jpa

This is my query on SQL Server:

```
select count(*) from noleggi 
where id_utente = 1 AND id_libro =25 and GETDATE() BETWEEN inizio_prestito AND fine_prestito
```

Which is the correct syntax using JPA Repository?

I tried this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(n) from Noleggio n " +
            "WHERE  n.libroId = ?1 AND n.utenteId=?2 AND CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN n.inizioPrestito AND n.finePrestito")

    Long countByUtenteIdAndLibroId(Long idLibro, Long idUtente, LocalDate inizioPrestito, LocalDate finePrestito);
```

And received this error:

> Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long com.finance.biblioteca.repository.NoleggioRepository.countByUtenteIdAndLibroId(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate

Comment: Did not work what you tried?

Comment: no, it dosen't work

Comment: Did you receive some error? No results? Tell us what happened.

Comment: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long com.finance.biblioteca.repository.NoleggioRepository.countByUtenteIdAndLibroId(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date>` interface with its two methods `convertToDatabaseColumn` and `convertToEntityAttribute`.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

please refer to this link for more details. https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

My thought on your issue is that you don't have parameters for the `BETWEEN`. You just put field as name and not as [indexed](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) parameters.
Your code should looks something like this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(n) from Noleggio n " +
            "WHERE  n.libroId = ?1 AND n.utenteId=?2 AND CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN ?3 AND ?4")

    Long countByUtenteIdAndLibroId(Long idLibro, Long idUtente, LocalDate inizioPrestito, LocalDate finePrestito);
```

Depending on your version of JPA, you will need or not to write your own [LocalDateConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840769/how-to-persist-localdate-with-jpa) as mentionned in the response above.

Comment: select * from noleggi 
where id_utente = 1 AND id_libro =25 and GETDATE() BETWEEN inizio_prestito AND fine_prestito

Comment: my query have to count if my current date is between my two dates into database refered to UserID with that specific bookID

Comment: i tried that                                                                                           
 @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(n) FROM Noleggio n WHERE idutente= :idUtente AND idlibro = :idLibro AND :data BETWEEN n.inizioPrestito AND n.finePrestito")   
                                                                                                                   Long countByNoleggioUtenteIdAndLibroId(@Param("idUtente") Long idUtente, @Param("idLibro") Long IdLibro, @Param("data")LocalDate data);

Comment: THE error is:                                 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'idutente'.

Comment: Ok its is more clear for me now. This error means that there is no a column with the name `idutente` in your table. Check and correct the name if needed.

Comment: yes, I solved! the column into database is with underscore, thanks!