# Is there any way to receive List<LocalDate> by Spring Boot JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Im trying to receive the LocalDate attribute of an entity. But I got a cannot convert type exception. And Im trying search answers by Spring Boot JPA document, but nothing helpful.

**Gradle Config**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**Configuration**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: sa
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 100

  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

**Entity**

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "db_test")
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Integer age;
    private LocalDate birthday;
}
```

**Repository**

```java
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, String> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT DISTINCT birthday from db_test")
    List<LocalDate> findAllBirthday();

}
```

**Test Method**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    @Test
    public void findAllBirthday() {
        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity("OK", 1, LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01"));
        testRepository.save(entity);

        List<LocalDate> result = testRepository.findAllBirthday();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, result.size());
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<java.time.LocalDate>] for value '[2019-01-01, 2019-01-02, 2019-01-03]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.sql.Date] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.time.LocalDate]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
```

---

Additional information:

Maybe Im not express my thought well. Here is my operation:

1. using H2 as default database.
2. writing JUnit4 test method.
3. running test under spring boot test environment.
4. hoping there will return List, BUT ONLY GOT EXCEPTION.

Comment: Try annotating birthday with `@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")`    (best guess from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840769/how-to-persist-localdate-with-jpa and https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time )

Comment: It depends how did you defined your table structure. In case you are using MySql and DATETIME Column. Then you must use java.sql.Timestamp to retrieve that information, then you might go for conversion as per your choice of DateFormatter

Answer (score 0):

How do you create fields in the database? If you're using MySQL your birthday field data type must as DATE!
otherwise, this is expected because of casting.

Comment: I used `create-drop` strategy. Im trying to debug to find out. the return type is a List<Timestamp>, and converting exception happened on List<Timestamp> to List<LocalDate>. Because JPA's  conversion service is a static service object, and its converters not contains any Timestamp translate method.

Comment: can you please verify me date format from your DB and type too? it might be YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

IT IS WILL NOT FIXED BY YOUR SELF!

Spring JPA convert database data by converters. And when you are querying for Timestamp data, there is no such convert for Timestamp to LocalDate as default.

Also JPA's converters not like Spring MVC's, custom converts will not added to JPA converts, it always using system default static ones.